# Problem with setting a login option for xampp phpmyadmin

Tags: authentication, phpmyadmin, xampp

I'm working on a school project in which we have to make a website using XAMPP and phpmyadmin. Currently i've changed the "Require localhost" to "Require all granted" in the httpd-xampp.conf so my mate can make changes in phpmyadmin. The problem is that EVERYONE can now join without a password and mess around. I've read a thread where it said that i need to change `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`  to  `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` within the phpmyadmin/config.inc.php file, which does not work for me.

How can i make it work so i have a login option to phpmyadmin?

Comment: You can create users in MySQL with passwords.

Comment: Note that *phpMyAdmin* is just a php tool to manage MySQL/MariaDB databases. Your database can be accessed and managed by *MySQL Workbench* too.